# Facebook is crashing [500 Internal Server Error]

Tags: facebook, share

Facebook is crashing when try to share a link using www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php. It give "**500 Internal Server Error**" for the first time. Following are the steps to reproduce the same:

1. Log-in to facebook first before you share anything.
2. Try to share any link which never shared on facebook and its a brand new link.
3. You can try any of the following link:

   - http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.remax.pt/marketing/published/a37bf4ec-e9ff-4abc-9afb-9ee7c14005da/post.html
   - http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.remax.pt/marketing/published/7108fd7a-eb16-4d20-8ee5-2368c35fdc01/post.html

***Note:***

1. If you are not logged-in to facebook and try to post those links then it will work fine and popup will be closed after posting that to facebook.
2. If you are logged-in then it will give you error for the first time and if you try to share again by closing the current window and open again in separate window then it will start working.

I tried it on different websites as well and they are having same issue. e.g.

1. Register at imgur.com
2. Upload any image.
3. Try to share it on facebook.
4. You will get the same issue.

Comment: Maybe contact Facebook instead of stackoverflow?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not, never have been, and probably never will be, Facebook technical support.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid FB bug, it appears to be that they are looking at it here
see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/795945327148024/